# Using the Color Burn method in Python

Tags: python, image-processing

I tried to apply the Color Brun method when connecting two images, but I got something unclear

I am creating a screen in tkiner so that I can change the overlay image (there is text in black letters) I can change its dimensions, coordinates, and color (from black to white), but the overlay effect is not the same as in Photoshop, although I try to use the same method

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageOps, ImageDraw, ImageTk, ImageFilter
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Scale, Label
from os import getenv
import cv2
import numpy as np


# Глобальные переменные
desired_width = 550
y_offset = 150
x_offset = 43
enhance_factor = 1

# Функция для обновления изображения
def update_image(event):
    global desired_width, y_offset, x_offset, enhance_factor

    desired_width = width_scale.get()
    y_offset = offset_scale.get()
    x_offset = x_offset_scale.get()
    enhance_factor = enhance_scale.get()

    # Открываем основное изображение и слой с затемнением
    base_image = Image.open("4.png").convert("RGBA") #D:\\Рабочий стол\\avito\\
    darken_layer = Image.open("PRICOL.png").convert("RGBA") #D:\\Рабочий стол\\avito\\
    darkened_layer = darken_layer

    # Уменьшаем размер darken_layer, сохраняя пропорции
    original_width, original_height = darkened_layer.size
    ratio = desired_width / original_width
    new_height = int(original_height * ratio)
    darkened_layer = darkened_layer.resize((desired_width, new_height))

    new_darkened_layer = Image.new('RGBA', base_image.size, (0, 0, 0, 0))
    new_darkened_layer.paste(darkened_layer, (x_offset, y_offset))

    factor = enhance_factor  # Множитель осветления (1.0 оставит изображение без изменений)
    new_darkened_layer = new_darkened_layer.point(lambda p: p * factor)

    # Создайте новое изображение, чтобы сохранить результат
    #result_image = Image.new('RGBA', base_image.size, (0, 0, 0, 0))

    #new_darkened_layer.save("D:\\Рабочий стол\\avito\\4_burn.png")
    #base_image.save("D:\\Рабочий стол\\avito\\4_not_burn.png")

    img1 = base_image.copy()
    img2 = new_darkened_layer.copy()


    pixel_data1 = img1.load()
    pixel_data2 = img2.load()

    # Наложение эффекта BURN на изображения
    for i in range(img1.size[0]):
        for j in range(img1.size[1]):
            r1, g1, b1, a1 = pixel_data1[i, j]
            r2, g2, b2, a2 = pixel_data2[i, j]
            r = 255 if r1 == 0 else min(1, 1 - (1 - r2 / 255) / (r1 / 255)) * 255
            g = 255 if g1 == 0 else min(1, 1 - (1 - g2 / 255) / (g1 / 255)) * 255
            b = 255 if b1 == 0 else min(1, 1 - (1 - b2 / 255) / (b1 / 255)) * 255
            
            pixel_data1[i, j] = (int(r), int(g), int(b), a1)
    blended_img = img1
    # Отображение основного изображения в tkinter окне
    blended_img = blended_img.resize((800, 600))
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(blended_img)
    image_label.config(image=img)
    image_label.image = img


# Создание графического интерфейса
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Настройка изображения")

# Ползунок для изменения ширины
width_label = Label(root, text="Desired Width:")
width_label.pack()
width_scale = Scale(root, from_=100, to=1000, orient="horizontal", length=500)
width_scale.set(desired_width)
width_scale.pack()
width_scale.bind("<Motion>", update_image)

# Ползунок для изменения вертикального смещения
offset_label = Label(root, text="Y Offset:")
offset_label.pack()
offset_scale = Scale(root, from_=10, to=400, orient="horizontal", length=500)
offset_scale.set(y_offset)
offset_scale.pack()
offset_scale.bind("<Motion>", update_image)

# Ползунок для изменения горизонтального смещения
x_offset_label = Label(root, text="X Offset:")
x_offset_label.pack()
x_offset_scale = Scale(root, from_=0, to=200, orient="horizontal", length=500)
x_offset_scale.set(x_offset)
x_offset_scale.pack()
x_offset_scale.bind("<Motion>", update_image)

# Ползунок для изменения яркости
enhance_label = Label(root, text="Enhance Factor:")
enhance_label.pack()
enhance_scale = Scale(root, from_=0, to=5, orient="horizontal", length=500, resolution=0.01)
enhance_scale.set(enhance_factor)
enhance_scale.pack()
enhance_scale.bind("<Motion>", update_image)

# Метка для отображения изображения
image_label = Label(root)
image_label.pack()

# Запуск графического интерфейса
root.mainloop()
```

Can you tell me which formula to use?

I used the formula B(A,F)=1−(1−A)/F
and got

Comment: Please click [edit] and complete your question. Please include the images you used and the results you got and the results you expected. If you used a blending formula, please link to where you got it from. If you want folks to help you, it's probably a good idea to make it easy for them. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
def color_burn(base_pixel, blend_pixel):
    """
    Apply Color Burn effect for two pixels.
    Each pixel is a tuple in the format (R, G, B, A)
    """
    result = []
    for i in range(3):  # Iterate over R, G, B channels
        if blend_pixel[i] == 0:
            result.append(base_pixel[i])  # Use the base value if blend pixel is 0
        else:
            value = 1 - (1 - base_pixel[i] / 255) / (blend_pixel[i] / 255)
            result.append(min(255, max(0, int(value * 255))))  # Clamp the result between 0 and 255
    result.append(base_pixel[3])  # Use the alpha from the base pixel
    return tuple(result)

def apply_color_burn(base_image, blend_image):
    """
    Apply Color Burn effect for two images.
    Both images should have the same dimensions.
    """
    result_image = Image.new('RGBA', base_image.size)
    base_pixels = base_image.load()
    blend_pixels = blend_image.load()
    result_pixels = result_image.load()

    for y in range(base_image.height):
        for x in range(base_image.width):
            result_pixels[x, y] = color_burn(base_pixels[x, y], blend_pixels[x, y])

    return result_image
```

Comment: Well done for adding your answer. It would be more helpful to future readers if you included all the necessary `import` statements, and showed how to call it, along with an input and corresponding output image.